# Flutter Unable to load asset

Tags: flutter, assets, flutter-dependencies

I could find this issue as quite common, but any of the suggestions didn't help me.

I want to simply show an image:

```
body: new Image.asset('rh.png',width:300,height:100),
```

You can see it is in the correct folder

[image]

It has correct place in `pubspec.yaml`

[image]

But I still get an error:

```
Unable to load asset: rh.png
```

I tried a lot of suggestions from `github` or `stackoverflow`, but none of them helped me; played with spaces and tabs in `.yaml` file (doing `flutter clean` after each attempt), tried to rename `.png` file and put it in the subfolder - no success. Where is the catch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your path to your .png file.
It should address properly to the file location.

Correct form would be something like below:

```
new Image(image: AssetImage('assets/rh.png')),
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add `assets` with the filename:

Correct way is: `new Image.asset('assets/rh.png', width:300, height:100)`

Answer (score 2):

**Complete image path should be passed for fetching any asset file**

in your case using `assets/rh.png` would resolve the error